# How to restrict youtube videos to a specific quality using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension to save data and I need to be able to restrict the quality of youtube videos to always be like 360p, not auto. How can I do that?

Comment: You would probably be better off by forcing a quality choice on the quality selector than trying to manipulate the media data.

Comment: I guess you're right, but I don't know how to do that. Can you please write it as an answer?